# click behind a continually rendered element

Tags: meteor

I'm rendering a video progress bar with the following:

```
<div class="video-timeline">
  {{#isolate}}
    <div style="width: {{progressBarWidth}}" class="video-progress-bar"></div>
  {{/isolate}}
</div>
```

The progress bar fits inside the timeline and extends to the right as the video's time advances (based on a session variable). The goal is to observe clicks on the timeline so I can change the play location.

Click events on the timeline to the right of the progress bar are observed correctly. However, while the video is playing (and the progress bar is being continually rendered) a click on the  progress bar itself will infrequently bubble up to the timeline click handler.

**How can I observe these events, or is there a better way to do this altogether?**

**Update:** Using an overlay (as suggested by datacarl) is probably best if you absolutely need to have an element which is updated multiple times a second and controlled by meteor. This worked for me but, I ended up reverting to a jQuery-based solution for that particular part of the template. As much as I dislike mixing jQuery events and meteor events, jQuery was provided a more responsive and less error-prone way to update the progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to handle this is to absolute position a div.progress-bar-overlay on top of div.video-progress-bar and observe the clicks on .progress-bar-overlay instead. Give it the same height and width as .video-timeline. That way you do not have to handle whether the user clicks on the .video-timeline or on the .video-progress-bar.

Comment: Yep, that was my plan if no meteor-specific trickery could be found. The annoying thing is that all of this worked fine with a jQuery-based event system. The migration to meteor landed me with this issue.